# Set a value in attribute field

Tags: acumatica

I wanted to know the best method to update an attribute. This works, but does not seem optimal to me.

```
protected void VendorR_RowXXXXXXXX(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (VendorR)e.Row;
  if (row==null) return;

  string activite="COLOR";
  CSAnswers une_reponseav= PXSelect<CSAnswers,Where<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<Required<CSAnswers.attributeID>>,And<CSAnswers.refNoteID,Equal<Required<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>>>>.Select(this.Base,activite,row.NoteID);
  if (une_reponseav!=null)
  {
    une_reponseav.Value="RED";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most data entry graphs, the attributes cache is named "Answers".  So if you have a specific attribute you want to update in your answers cache, it's simple

```
CSAnswer a = Base.Answers.Search<CSAnswer.refNoteID>(Base.Answers.Cache, "some GUID");
a.Value = "whatever"
graph.Answers.Update(a);
```